# How do we handle ambiguous tag names?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that the tag for Original D&D is "odd." Will people realize that this is for OD&D? Will there be confusion with odd/strange?

I think this another point in favor of retagging the D&D-related things as "dnd" and so on.

Comment: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-the-dd-tags-be-without-an-ampersand is the original question; [dnd] is the highest rank solution. People should possibly be retagging!

Answer (score 2):

We make sure there's useful information in the tag wiki! [[odd]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/odd/) has a good one, which is nice.

Comment: Can someone add edit that please? It needs editing badly with all the &amp's

Comment: Oh! I did not know there was a tag wiki. I am glad I asked.

Comment: I am too! Oh, hm, and another comment, coming as a comment.

Comment: @Jere -- fixed, thanks.

Comment: The odnd tag has no wiki, would you like to help us create it?

Comment: Um, that really sucks. We lost the odd wiki info when we created the synonym. It was pretty good, too. :(

Answer (score 0):

When it's unclear what the meaning of the tag is, but there's one clearly superior use, I think the wiki is enough. But there are systems named "Adventure!" "Warlord," "Wushu," "Bushido," "Wushu," and "Wild Talent," all of which could conceivably be used as tags for other things. "-" is already in use to combine two words into an atomic tag, and I think that should be the sole use for "-". When or if it becomes necessary, I think "." should be used to append disambiguations. [adventure.system] or [adventure.game] is still going to be confusing, but at least there would be an underlying logic capable of being discovered and explained.

Comment: hybrid tags should not be used.  I understand the problem you are pointing out but that is not the solution.

Comment: Does a solution exist?

Comment: Oh, wait, more questions: (1) Why should hybrid tags not be used? (2) What are hybrid tags? (3) Do you consider [dice-notation] or [system-recommendation] hybrid tags?